# Static bootstraping constructor

Tags: typescript, static

While I was searching how to migrate to typescript my nodejs code, I found something like this:

```
class Server {
  public app: any;

  constructor() {
    this.app = express();

  }

  public static bootstrap(): Server {
    return new Server();
  }
}
```

Which is used so:

```
const app = Server.bootstrap().app;
```

My question is, what is the advantage of use an static method over using the normal constructor, is it a best practice or depends on the use case. Is it a design pattern?

Answer (score 0):

The static keyword defines a static method for a class. Static methods aren't called on instances of the class. Instead, they're called on the class itself. These are often utility functions, such as functions to create or clone objects. Where you don't need to maintain any state.

Ex: Number.isInteger().
You can call static functions without instantiating it.

In your current example you basically created a function to instantiate the very same class. I dont think its necessary until there is any other use cases in your mind.